# python gives different result run through command and browser

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am using python 2.7 and opencv 3.1 on aws linux for image processing. when i run python script through command and if i run python script through php exec command on browser, in both cases its give different output result.

below are the different result :

original image : 
[image]

Terminal output :
[image]

Output when run the python script through browser

[image]

Comment: You are obviously doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: same code script i am running through command and browser

Comment: Then something else other than your code is causing the problem and at this point, there is nothing I can do to help you except you provide some more information

Comment: I would suggest that your terminal and your PHP code are running different versions of Python. Perhaps run `sys.version` to check this.